# UserDialog Progress Bar does not show up

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to show progress bar during the network operation, but it does not increments up. It stays with 2.

[image]

```
public async Task SyncPopulationDataAsync(string countryId)
{
    var cancelled = false;

    using (var dlg = Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Progress("Test Progress", () => cancelled = true))
    {
        while (dlg.PercentComplete < 100)
        {
           dlg.PercentComplete += 2;
           await Task.Run(() => SyncPopulationData(countryId)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Using ConfigureAwait false placing the next while loop onto the context of the Task.Run thread and thus you are no longer updating dlg.PercentComplete on the main/UI thread.

Comment: @SushiHangover, what would be the solution?

Comment: Simply remove the ConfigureAwait... or use ConfigureAwait true, or use a ContinueWith supplying the TaskScheduler with the UI context. ConfigureAwait false is great on non-UI services as there is "typically" no reason to change the thread context on Task completion and thus avoid the context switch overhead, MS has some Task best practices docs on their site that are actually a great read, beware there are also some really bad blog posts from random people that say ConfigureAwait false should be used on each and every Task :-/

Comment: How could I able to estimate the time of progress to finish at the same with network operation?

Comment: I have removed ConfigureAwait(false) part, but it is still same.

Comment: `You should not use ConfigureAwait when you have code after the await in the method that needs the context. For GUI apps, this includes any code that manipulates GUI elements, writes data-bound properties or depends on a GUI-specific type such as Dispatcher/CoreDispatcher. ` From one of MS docs... it does say to use ConfigureAwait false whenever possible (as the doc was written with a view of the conversion of your synchronous app to an asynchronous one), but as the passage states, do not use it for UI updates. When you are *already* within a non-UI Task thread, use it and avoid the overhead.

Comment: Check the thread id when you update `dlg.PercentComplete`